# Sending an array from Mongo to React with Node

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, mongodb

I have a mongo database which holds a short list of movie titles with some extra data. In my React App I call the server which in turns gets the data from Mongo via mongoose. The data is returned and sent to the App. This all goes swimmingly. Inside the App I want to parse this data dynamically on the page. Now I noticed that React doesn't allow Objects as children, which is OK because for my dynamic render I want to change the Object to an array anyway (otherwise `.map()` won't work for instance). However for some reason or another I can *not* get the data sent over as an array!

**Server**

```
app.get('/database', (req, res) => {

    Movie.find()
        .then(movies => {
            let movieArr = Object.values(movies); // IF I JUST SEND MOVIEARR I GET AN ERROR

   
            let dataArr = [];

            movieArr.map(movie =>
            dataArr.push(movie.title)); // SO I CREATED A SIMPLIFIED ARRAY WHICH DOES WORK

            res.send(dataArr)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send({error: "Movie.find() error = " + err})
        })
});
```

My question is: isn't the original `movieArr` already an array? I can perform `.map()` on it , so why should I push it to another array for React to work? The annoying thing is that I don't want to push separate pieces of data, I want the array to contain all data and then to call the data in React.

For the full picture:

**App**

```
class Database extends Component {
    state = {
        listOfMovies: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.callServerForDatabase()
            .then(data => this.setState({ listOfMovies: data }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

    callServerForDatabase = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/database');
        const body = await response.json();
        
        const data = Object.values(body);

        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
        return data;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Data>
                <p>List Of Movies</p>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Movie Title</th>
                            <th>IMDB</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            {this.state.listOfMovies.map(movie =>
                            <tr>
                            <td>{movie}</td>
                            </tr>)}
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                )
    }

}
```

**ERROR**

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, title, smn, rtc, mtc, imdb, comments, __v}}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Full data sent to React should look like this:

```
[
 { "title": "Alien",
  "imdb": "90",
   //... etc.
 },
 { "title": "Aliens",
  "imdb": "87",
   //... etc.
},

]
```

And preferably be accessible like `this.state.listOfMovies[0].imdb`. Probably also good to know that I am using typescript.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT (FIXED!) :

I needed to call `{movies.title}` inside the `.map` function because otherwise I would render out objects as children. I then encountered the problem of an empty array as initialState. After adding a movie to 'start with' it no longer had a problem with the initial render and performed the `componentDidMount()` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you map it, you're returning only a string (title property):

```
movieArr.map(movie =>dataArr.push(movie.title));
```

So it works in the below expression:

```
<td>{movie}</td>
```

For the original, React is saying that you instead expressed with "{movie}" the following object :

> found: object with keys {_id, title, smn, rtc, mtc, imdb, comments, __v}

And it can't use an object as a child, so if you instead did:

```
<td>{movie.title}</td>
```

The error would resolve. (it isn't an issue with map, but rather your expression)

On a side note:

```
const dataArr = movieArr.map(movie => movie.title);
```

Would be the correct way to use map; what you have is suited for forEach

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use ```{movie.title}``` it works for 1 second before crashing and giving me an error: ```"Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339"```

Comment: The plot thickens. I can render ```{this.state.listOfMovies[0]}``` which gives me an object with (among others) a key of "title" but ```{this.state.listOfMovies[0].title}``` gives the same "type never" error.

Comment: FIXED! The problem was that I initialized the Component with an empty array (listOfMovies) so the problem happened at the first render *before* the componentDidMount(). Still thanks a million for getting the thought process happening!